# Problems matching values from nested dictionary

Tags: python, testrail

In TestRail, I have created several testruns.  When I execute:

```
test_runs = client.send_get('get_runs/1')
pprint(test_runs)
```

The following results are returned:

```
{'_links': {'next': None, 'prev': None},
 'limit': 250,
 'offset': 0,
 'runs': [{'assignedto_id': None,
           'blocked_count': 0,
           'completed_on': None,
           'config': None,
           'config_ids': [],
           'created_by': 1,
           'created_on': 1651790693,
           'custom_status1_count': 0,
           'custom_status2_count': 0,
           'custom_status3_count': 0,
           'custom_status4_count': 0,
           'custom_status5_count': 0,
           'custom_status6_count': 0,
           'custom_status7_count': 0,
           'description': None,
           'failed_count': 1,
           'id': 13,
           'include_all': False,
           'is_completed': False,
           'milestone_id': None,
           'name': '2022-05-05-testrun',
           'passed_count': 2,
           'plan_id': None,
           'project_id': 1,
           'refs': None,
           'retest_count': 0,
           'suite_id': 1,
           'untested_count': 0,
           'updated_on': 1651790693,
           'url': 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.testrail.io/index.php?/runs/view/13'},
          {'assignedto_id': None,
           'blocked_count': 0,
           'completed_on': 1650989972,
           'config': None,
           'config_ids': [],
           'created_by': 5,
           'created_on': 1650966329,
           'custom_status1_count': 0,
           'custom_status2_count': 0,
           'custom_status3_count': 0,
           'custom_status4_count': 0,
           'custom_status5_count': 0,
           'custom_status6_count': 0,
           'custom_status7_count': 0,
           'description': None,
           'failed_count': 0,
           'id': 9,
           'include_all': False,
           'is_completed': True,
           'milestone_id': None,
           'name': 'This is a new test run',
           'passed_count': 0,
           'plan_id': None,
           'project_id': 1,
           'refs': None,
           'retest_count': 0,
           'suite_id': 1,
           'untested_count': 3,
           'updated_on': 1650966329,
           'url': 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.testrail.io/index.php?/runs/view/9'}],
 'size': 2}
```

In my code, I am trying to scan through all of the resulting testruns, locate the testrun I'm interested in by matching the testrun name, and then have the ID for the testrun returned.

```
from pprint import pprint
from testrail import *


class connecting():
    def connectPostRun(self):
        client = APIClient('https://xxxxxxxxxx.testrail.io')
        client.user = 'abc@abc.com'
        client.password = 'abc123'

        test_run_name = '2022-05-05-testrun'

        test_runs = client.send_get('get_runs/1')
        pprint(test_runs)

        for test_run in test_runs:
            if test_run['name'] == test_run_name:
                run_id = test_run['id']
                break

        return run_id
        pprint(run_id)

c=connecting()
c.connectPostRun()
```

Executing the code as is now results in the following error:

```
    if test_run['name'] == test_run_name:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: If your `pprint` output is correct, you are iterating over the keys of a dictionary when doing `for test_run in test_runs`. These you cannot index with `[` like this.

Comment: Try `test_runs = client.send_get('get_runs/1').json()['runs']`, if the current result is a string you will need to convert it to an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping over the wrong part of the datastructure that the function returned. The loop `for test_run in test_runs:` only iterates over the keys of the top-level dictionary (`"_links"`, `"limit"`, etc.).

You want to be looping over `test_runs['runs']`, which will give you dictionaries with the `"name"` keys you're matching against. Try making your loop look like this:

```
    for test_run in test_runs['runs']:
        if test_run['name'] == test_run_name:
            run_id = test_run['id']
            break
```

I'd note that there's a potential problem in this code, that if you never find a matching run, the `run_id` variable will never be assigned to, so the `return` statement at the end of the function will raise an exception. If you think that could ever happen, you should probably either set a default value, or perhaps raise your own exception (with a more clear message) if you get into that situation.